# My website has a very unusual setup, completely done with aws, s3, cloudwatch, and lambda. Why isn't it working?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I know I'm probably going to get harassed about this setup, but I'm running two websites through aws route 53 and aws s3 buckets. I needed to password protect a subsite (the word's slipping my mind at the moment but basically ex.example.com instead of just example.com). The only way to do this, however, was to make a second s3 bucket and run all requests for that subsite through 1) my old example.com route 53 hosted zone, 2) a new hosted zone for ex.example.com, 3) a cloudwatch (or is it cloudflare? I get the two mixed up) page to redirect http to https, 4) a lambda function that makes you input a username and password, and finally 5) back to that second s3 bucket I was talking about.

So it WAS working, but now it's... not. I enter the correct name and pass, and it just gives me this:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>XXXXXXXXXX</RequestId>
<HostId>
XXXXXXXXXXXX
</HostId>
</Error>
```

I took out the requestID and the hostID because I'm not sure if those are sensitive information.

Here's my Lambda function, COMPLETELY copied from the internet because I have zero idea of how lambda works

```
'use strict';

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    // Get request and request headers
    const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
    const headers = request.headers;

    // Configure authentication
    const authUser = 'XXXX';
    const authPass = 'XXXXXXXX';

    // Construct the Basic Auth string
    const authString = 'Basic ' + new Buffer(authUser + ':' + authPass).toString('base64');

    // Require Basic authentication
    if (typeof headers.authorization == 'undefined' || headers.authorization[0].value != authString) {
        const body = 'Unauthorized';
        const response = {
            status: '401',
            statusDescription: 'Unauthorized',
            body: body,
            headers: {
                'www-authenticate': [{key: 'WWW-Authenticate', value:'Basic'}]
            },
        };
        callback(null, response);
    }

    // Continue request processing if authentication passed
    callback(null, request);
};
```

It's just not working (it should be directing me to ex.example.com's index which is what's set in the 'index document' line in the static website hosting section of the properties of ex.example.com's s3 bucket), and I THINK the issue is with the Lambda function. Someone please help!! Thanks :)

Oh, and one more thing. The redirect from my example.com sends me to "ex.example.com/?" instead of just "ex.example.com". I don't think this means anything, however, because I get the same result when I delete the "/?" and hit enter.

Shit I just remembered something else... it may be because my s3 bucket's settings are wrong. Here's my Bucket Policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity XXXXXXXXXXX"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::www.ex.example.com/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity XXXXXXXXXXX"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::www.ex.example.com/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Thank you SO much!!!

Comment: Rather than trying to debug your current setup, we might be able to suggest a better way of achieving your goal. Can you please edit your question and explain **the end-state of what you are trying to achieve**? For example, do you want some public pages and some private pages? Are the private pages fully accessible to anyone who knows a password, or does access to each page depend upon the particular person who authenticated? Tell us more, please.

Comment: Yes! My end goal is to have a public page, example.com that has a field on it for a password. Upon entering that password, you'd be taken to admin.example.com, which is unaccessible unless you enter the password. I also want pages like admin.example.com/file1.jpg/ that can't be accessed unless you've entered the password. Does that clear things up?